# is there a function that can remove a list of strings from another list of different type?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to remove a list(type String) of items from a larger list (type CustomType) of a different type. To do this, I'm using a minus() function in kotlin, but I'm getting a Type mismatch warning in IntelliJ. How to handle such scenarios in kotlin.

```
fun someMethod(A: CustomTypeA): List<CustomTypeB> {

    val list_1: List<CustomTypeB> = listOf()

    // some logic that puts values into list_1

    if (list_1.count > 0) {
        return list_1.minus(
            A.excludelist
        ) // type mismatch: inferred type is String! but CustomTypeB was expected
    }
}
```

Comment: What relates `CustomType` to `String`? Use that to compare.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You will never remove anything this way. A list of `CustomTypeB` could never contain any `String`s. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Sweeper CustomTypeB is a dynamodb data model I want to make sure that the result of my function to be CustomTypeB so that can be consumed by someother function

Comment: What does it even mean you want to remove strings from a list of not-strings? This is subtracting apples from oranges. Do you mean these custom objects have a property of string type and you want to exclude based on this property?

Comment: @broot yes you right!

Comment: `val filteredList = sourceList.filter { it.someStringProperty !in excludeList }` If either of the lists is huge, change `excludeList` into a Set (once before using it in this filter lambda) for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to exclude the elements matching them via some property.

If so, minimal working example:

```kotlin
    data class Exclude(val excludeList: List<String>)
    data class Result(val prop: String)
    
    fun someMethod(exclude: Exclude): List<Result> {

        val list1: List<Result> = listOf()
        // fill the list...

        return list1.filterNot { x -> x.prop in exclude.excludeList }
    }
```

So, instead of "removing" what we do here is filtering. There is no need to add `isEmpty` check - filtering on empty list will return empty list anyway.

Or, there is another way to do that, with operator overriding:

At first, define the operator:

```kotlin
    operator fun List<Result>.minus(toRemove: List<String>): List<Result> {
        return this.filterNot { x -> x.prop in toRemove }
    }
```

Then, you can make a call you expected:

```kotlin
return list1 - exclude.excludeList
// or
return list1.minus(exclude.excludeList)
```

But, while overriding operator, a very good practice is to define all possible operators for the consistency (I mean you should override operator `minusAssign` as well). So, IMHO, in your case it's better to just use filtering in place. :)